# Openstack odes not have nay flavours/images

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon

I tried creating a basic network in openstack, but the selection for instances and flavours are empty.

How do I load instances/flavours into open stack? and where can I get them from.

Comment: The flavors are contained in the nova database (there is a command to create the tables and the first 5 basic flavors, you can also add your own). As for the instances, Jarek is right, you need to add images and you then use them to create instances.

Answer (score 0):

You don't load instances into Openstack. You load images, ISOs etc... Try CirrOS first for testing.

Once you load an image you can create an instance.